# On product description page show size/weight of product after its name?

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, xml

How can I show product weight/size in product description page ? after name of product ?

I have field to set weight on backend 
[image]

And code of span is

```
<span data-bind="attr: {'data-config-scope': $data.scopeLabel}, text: label" data-config-scope="[GLOBAL]">Weight</span>
```

My catalog_product_view.xml file code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 

<!-- 
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> 
--> 
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> 
<body> 
<referenceContainer name="content" > 
<!-- <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/topattributes.phtml" name="product.info.topattribute" after="product.info.media"> 
</block>  -->
<block class="Infortis\Base\Block\Product\View" name="product-view-wrapper" template="product/view.phtml" before="-"> </block> 
<container name="container_product_image_1" label="Product View, Image Column" /> 
<container name="container_product_primary_1" label="Product View, Primary Column, Container 1" /> 
<container name="container_product_primary_2" label="Product View, Primary Column, Container 2" /> 
<container name="container_product_secondary_1" label="Product View, Secondary Column, Container 1" /> 
<container name="container_product_secondary_2" label="Product View, Secondary Column, Container 2" /> 
<container name="container_product_lower_primary_1" label="Product View, Lower Primary Column, Container 1" /> 
<container name="container_product_lower_primary_2" label="Product View, Lower Primary Column, Container 2" /> 
<container name="container_product_lower_secondary_1" label="Product View, Lower Secondary Column, Container 1" /> 
<container name="container_product_lower_secondary_2" label="Product View, Lower Secondary Column, Container 2" /> 
<!-- Static blocks --> 
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_product_secondary_bottom"> 
<arguments> 
<argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_product_secondary_bottom</argument> 
</arguments> 
</block> 
</referenceContainer> 
<!-- Reset attributes of main containers --> 
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main" htmlTag="" htmlClass="" before="-" /> 
<referenceContainer name="product.info.media" htmlTag="" htmlClass="" after="product.info.main" /> 
<!-- Insert product view blocks into the new product view wrapper --> 
<move element="product.info.main" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 
<move element="product.info.media" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 
<move element="bundle.options.container" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 
<move element="product.info.details" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 
<move element="catalog.product.related" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 
<move element="product.info.upsell" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 

<!-- Move some blocks to new positions --> 
<!-- <move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.price" after="product.price.final" /> --> 
<!-- <move element="product.info.social" destination="product.info.main" after="-" /> --> 
<move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.price" /> 
<move element="container_product_primary_1" destination="product.info.main" after="page.main.title" /> 
<move element="container_product_primary_2" destination="product.info.main" after="-" /> 
<!-- Move some blocks outside the "product.info.main" to manipulate their position inside template file --> 
<move element="page.main.title" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 
<move element="product.info.review" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 
<!-- Product collateral data (tabs) --> 
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details" template="Infortis_Base::product/view/details.phtml" > <arguments> 
<argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Kit Components</argument> 
<argument name="show_tabs" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::showTabs" /> 
</arguments> 
<!-- Custom static blocks as tabs --> 
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="product_cms_block1" group="detailed_info"> 
<arguments> 
<argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_product_tab1</argument> 
<argument name="title" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::getStaticBlockTitle"> 
<param name="id">block_product_tab1</param> 
</argument> 
</arguments> 
</block> 
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="product_cms_block2" group="detailed_info"> 
<arguments> 
<argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_product_tab2</argument> 
<argument name="title" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::getStaticBlockTitle"> 
<param name="id">block_product_tab2</param> 
</argument> 
</arguments> 
</block> 
</referenceBlock> 
<referenceBlock name="catalog.product.related" > 
<action method="setTemplate"> 
<argument name="template" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::getRelatedProductsTemplate" /> 
</action> 
</referenceBlock> 
<referenceBlock name="product.info.upsell" hide="true"> 
<action method="setTemplate"> 
<argument name="template" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::getUpsellProductsTemplate" /> 
<!-- TODO: --> 
<argument name="is_responsive" xsi:type="string">false</argument> 
<argument name="show_items" xsi:type="string">3</argument> 
</action> 
</referenceBlock> 
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.crosssell" hide="true"> 
<action method="setTemplate"> 
<argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Infortis_Base::product/list/slider.phtml</argument> 
</action> 
</referenceBlock> 
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/topattributes.phtml" name="product.info.topattribute"  after="product.info.main"/>      
</referenceContainer>
<move element="reviews.tab" destination="main.content" after="-"/>
</body> 
</page>
```

Comment: in which version , you want to show

Comment: Sorry I should remove 1.9 @AmitBera  2.1 it is

Comment: magento 2.1 it is

Comment: @lerner It is attribute right? to show your attributes on the frontend you need to make it active to show at frontend

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI how ?  I gave value in  field on admin side . but it is not appearing on front side , where to active this ?

Comment: first tell me it is attribute or something else?

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI i updated question

Comment: from span code I think its attr @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI

Comment: see my answer may it is helpful to you!!

Comment: this is not the code of `catalog_product_view.xml`  you need to check the `catalog_product_view.xml` file available at `magento_root_directory\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml`

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI  I cant replace that code as I have done so much work in it

Comment: @learner Did it worked?

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI  No I think as I am using ultimo paid theme. here is different scenario working

Comment: go & find the block file & phtml files given in this code may be you will get something there to solve your problem  

`<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/topattributes.phtml" name="product.info.topattribute"  after="product.info.main"/>      
</referenceContainer>`

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI  can you see this code at the end of file I uploaded ? you talking about that "topattribute" this is made by me , a custom attribute to add images and videos.

Comment: simply just put the code given in my answer into your xml file below `<container name="product.info.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-main" before="-">`

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI  I did according to your answer below , I copied vendor code , now its appearing in sku div while I want it to appear after product name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66256/discussion-between-abhishek-tripathi-and-learner).

Comment: If my answer was help full to you don't forget to vote & accept so it can be helpful to others as well facing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Simply copy the xml file available at `magento_root_directory\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml`

And paste it into your theme directory at `magento_root_directory\app\design\frontend\Alothemes\default\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml`

put there this code

```
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.sku" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" after="product.info.type">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getWeight</argument>
            <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">weight</argument>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">weight</argument>
            <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
            <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="weight"</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
```

like if you want to print it below your sku then just put it below your sku code it will looks like this after putting the code there

```
<container name="product.info.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-main" before="-">
            <container name="product.info.price" label="Product info auxiliary container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-price" after="product.info.review">
                <container name="product.info.stock.sku" label="Product auxiliary info" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-stock-sku">
                    <container name="product.info.type" before="-"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.sku" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" after="product.info.type">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getSku</argument>
                            <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
                            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
                            <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
                            <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="sku"</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                     <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.sku" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" after="product.info.type">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getWeight</argument>
                            <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">weight</argument>
                            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">weight</argument>
                            <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
                            <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="weight"</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </container>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.review" template="product/view/review.phtml" after="product.info.stock.sku" />
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.final" after="product.info.sku">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                        <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">final_price</argument>
                        <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.tier" after="product.info.price">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                    <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">tier_price</argument>
                    <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <container name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" label="Alert Urls" after="product.price.tier"/>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info" template="product/view/form.phtml" after="alert.urls">
                <container name="product.info.form.content" as="product_info_form_content">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
                </container>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product.info.form.options" as="options_container">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="product/view/options/wrapper.phtml">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="product/view/options.phtml">
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType" as="default" template="product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text" as="text" template="product/view/options/type/text.phtml"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File" as="file" template="product/view/options/type/file.phtml"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" as="select" template="product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date" as="date" template="product/view/options/type/date.phtml"/>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="Magento_Theme::js/calendar.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart.additional" as="product.info.addtocart" template="product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
            <container name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" label="Product View Extra Hint">
                <container name="product.info.social" label="Product social links container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-social-links" after="product.info.overview">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="product/view/addto.phtml">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AddTo\Compare" name="view.addto.compare" after="view.addto.wishlist"
                               template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto/compare.phtml" />
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.mailto" template="product/view/mailto.phtml"/>
                </container>
            </container>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.overview" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info" after="product.info.extrahint">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getShortDescription</argument>
                    <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">short_description</argument>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">overview</argument>
                    <argument name="at_label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Overview</argument>
                    <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="description"</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
```

simply replace your container with `name="product.info.main"` & than see your output

Comment: I already pasted that file in catalog_product_view.xml

Comment: I updated code of my catalog_view_product.xml   can you tell where to put that code ?

Comment: always use the default file of magento into your theme it will be beneficial for you other wise it will cause error when you need to upgrade your magento version or want to use any functionality of the magento

Comment: I am using ultimo theme and it came like this, I didnt changed so much

Comment: bro I made to appear this . but now weight is coming after description . I want it to appear after product name. what should I do now ?

Comment: It is in sku div while I want it to appear  weight after product name ?